# Extract items of integers from a regularly spaced list in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract every integer in a csv list in python, which can take different forms:

```
[[0, 3], [1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 0]]
```

or

```
[[0, 0, 3], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1], [0, 3, 0], [1, 0, 2], [1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0], [3, 0, 0]]
```

or even just

```
[[2]]
```

What I would like to do, is extract every integer from each element, and attach it to an x i.e for my first list produce `[x03, x12, x21, x30]` , or for the second produce `[x003, x021, x021, x030, x102, ....]`

I had been doing this by

```
  for i in range(len(gmomvec)):
    string=str(gmomvec[i])
    num=string[1::3]
    mm.append(Symbol('x'+num))
    ]
```

where gmomvec is the name of the list, and mm the resulting list I wish to obtain.
However I have just realised this is giving me incorrect results for the case where there are 2 integers in each list element. 
Does anyone know how I might use another function to do what I wish?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `list comprehension` and `str.join()`

```
>>> lis = [[0, 3], [1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 0]]
>>> ["x" + "".join(map(str,x))  for x in lis]
['x03', 'x12', 'x21', 'x30']

>>> lis = [[0, 0, 3], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1], [0, 3, 0], [1, 0, 2], [1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0], [3, 0, 0]]
>>> ["x" + "".join(map(str,x))  for x in lis]
['x003', 'x012', 'x021', 'x030', 'x102', 'x111', 'x120', 'x201', 'x210', 'x300']
```

`map(str, sequence)` applies the `str` function to each element of the sequence so that they can be concatenated using `str.join`

```
>>> map(str, [1,2,3])
['1', '2', '3']
```